# Cannot pass JSON array to array

Tags: arrays, json, swift2, swifty-json

I am trying to pass my JSON array to an array called `array` so that I can then query the array with `submission_id` with value 27 to obtain the `safety_rating_id`, `schedule_job_id`, `score` and `submission_id` from this JSON https://codeshare.io/UqJMV but I'm being thrown this error

> Cannot convert value of type '[JSON]' to expected argument type 'JSON'

Code to pass JSON to array:

```
var array: [JSON] = []

func getTask(onCompletion: () -> (), onError: ((NSError) -> ())? = nil) {

     guard let endPoint = Data.sharedInstance.weeklyEndpoint 
else { print("Empty endpoint"); return }

    Alamofire.request(.GET, endPoint, encoding: .JSON)
        .validate()
        .responseJSON { response in

        switch response.result {

        case .Success:
            if let value = response.result.value {
                let json = JSON(value)
                for (_,subJson):(String, JSON) in json {
                    if let date = subJson["start_date"].string{
                        self.date = date
                    }
                    if let building = subJson["building_name"].string{
                        self.building = building
                    }
                    if let jobId = subJson["schedule_job_id"].int {
                        self.jobIdArray.append(jobId)
                    }

                    if let tasks = subJson["tasks"].array{
                        Tasks.sharedInstance.datas = tasks
                        for building in tasks {
                            if let ratings = building["safety_ratings"].array{
                                print(ratings)

                                self.array.append(ratings)

                            }
                        }
                    }


                }

                onCompletion()
            }

        case .Failure(let error):
            print("Request failed with error: \(error)")
            onError?(error)
        }
    }      
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`append()` expects a single element (`JSON`), but `ratings` is an array (`[JSON]`).

That's what the error message says.

To append an array use `appendContentsOf`:

```
self.array.appendContentsOf(ratings)
```

Comment: How do I filter for the arrays with `submission_id = 27` inside? (I want to get the two dictionaries whose `submission_id` is 27)

Comment: `let filteredArray = array.filter {$0["submission_id"] as! Int == 27}`

Comment: it's throwing me a _Cast from 'JSON' to unrelated type 'Int' always fails_

Comment: You need to cast the `JSON` array to "normal" array probably `array.arrayValue.filter...`